# Shortcode with value from ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I've a Advanced Custom Field for my campaig : my_advanced_custom_field = 12223 and  I've a shortcode in my page that call my campaign

`[campaigns id=my_advanced_custom_field]`

Is it possible directly into a shortcode to put a ACF variable or should I use a php file ?

Comment: Do you mean in the page WYSIWYG editor? I think it impossible. You have to write some code in PHP

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to show ACF field values with a shortcode in your content.

This link has all the built-in shortcode possibilities of ACF:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/

But consider the limitations (you can find this on the page linked above):

**Limitations**

**- Only works for simple text based values**

If you want something done with the value or if you want some other type of ACF custom field displayed, then you have to write the necessary code.

Comment: thanks, but I need to embedd ACF Field shortcode INTO campaign shortcode, something like this : [campaigns id=[acf field="campaign_id"] columns=1]

Comment: If you want this, then you really need to write code. A WP shortcode does not accept a regular shortcode as a parameter. You can look at this WP Support topic: [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-as-parameter-to-another-shortcode](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-as-parameter-to-another-shortcode) to get some ideas.

Comment: I know this is super old.. but adding backslashes before the double quotes will render the shortcode ie: [shortcode id=\"myshortcode\"]

Answer (score 0):

Good example of php to a similar issue here:
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/broken-page-link-when-layered-on-top-of-text/#post-157183

You can adapt the code there (and the do_shortcode() ) to keep chaining the values through as far as you need.